# using android.hardware.camera2 to set custom resolution and frame rate

Tags: opencv, android-camera, android

I am trying to set a lower frame rate set for my application to detect objects in real time. I am also trying to set a lower resolution set as well.

I currently did that but using **"android.hardware.camera"** but this is deprecated in newer APIs (that is 21 and 22). I want to perform this by using **JavaCameraView** class so that i can include it through **OpenCV** and apply specific processing on the frames.

High resolution set would take too much processing power.

I am currently using **"android.hardware.camera2"** but i do not know how to change these parameters as done in previous API.

Code would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First try to use the last version of OpenCV Loader in you MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
}
```